# React sticky Navbar

Tags: reactjs, navbar, sticky

I'm trying to make my react navbar sticky and at the same time the logo and the items in the navbar should change colors when reaching each section . I am using a transparent navbar which shouldn't be visible until the top of the section is scrolled. The navbar is situated at the app.js file. Below is my folder structure of the react app I'm developing.(I'm not using the bootstrap Navbar)

[Folder_Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3181.png)

I tried a method provided by a blog which uses hooks to control the state .But I couldn't reference the element from the main section of my project to the app.

https://www.ibrahima-ndaw.com/blog/build-a-sticky-nav-with-react/

Any possible help to achieve this will be greatly helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Why did you post a screenshot of the folder structure?

Comment: @ziggystar To Give the clear view of what im trying to achieve.

Comment: I think I do not understand. What does a sticky navbar have to do with the layout of your project? Shouldn't you instead post some source code that shows your failed effort in implementing the navbar?

Comment: @ziggystar I'm new to this community . I'll include the source code which i tried

Answer (score 0):

You tried giving the navbar a class name and setting it to position to sticky on the app.css file?